# C#: php sprintf equivalent

Tags: c#, php, equivalent, string-formatting

I'm looking for a C# equivalent for the php sprintf function.

I have the folowing string:

```
"There are %s hits, %s are an exact match."
```

I want `%s` to be replaced with the numbers that the query returns. In php I would di the folowing:

```
$res = sprintf("There are %s hits, %s are an exact match", $number1, $number2);
```

How do I do this in C#? I thought about `string.replace()` but that would only work with 1 piece that should be replaced. In this case there are multiple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
String myStr = String.Format("There are {0} hits, {1} are an exact match",
                              number1, number2);
```

The format specifiers are a bit different than in PHP. [Here is an article explaining format specifiers](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/).

Comment: Crazy how 20 seconds between answers makes such a difference =/

Answer (score 3):

You use [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx).

```
string s = String.Format("There are {0} hits, {1} are an exact match", number1, number2);
```