# Need help to understand string.Format in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am not a c# programmer But I want to convert some code from c# to php. 
I could not understand proper meaning of following line.

```
i means my loop index
strVar.Add(string.Format("'{0}': '{1}'", (i + 1), fa["id"]));
```

I found following link but it is not that which I am looking for 
[C#: php sprintf equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329470/c-php-sprintf-equivalent)

Could not understand what exactly they mean As I am very new for c#  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: If you don't understand something, explain exactly what gives you trouble, especially when there are *so* many resources on the net that explain it.

Comment: string.Format is one of the most highly documented methods within .Net....did you even look at the docs?

Comment: @Adrian: Honestly, I didn't understand what you mean when I posted my comment. I thought you wanted to refer to the MSDN but used the name of some other documentation. I even googled for DNF and the results didn't shed any light (Disjunctive Normalform? no. Duke Nukem Forever? no.) ;-). Just right before you changed it I realized that you probably meant *.NET Framework*.

Comment: Why such negative votings here. Please tell the reason.

Comment: @Ay34: Because this method is explained in great detail all over the web.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth well its in http://www.acronymfinder.com/ as meaning the DotNetFramework --- but nowhere else! which makes me think I need to update my acronyms or just use .Net  ;-)

Comment: @Ay34 -1 because `string.Format` is probably the 2nd method that anyone who attempts to learn C# learns, `main()` being 1st.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would result in a string. Suppose `i + 1` would be `2` and `fa["id"]` is `567` then the resultant string would be:

```
"'2': '567'"
```

`{0}` and `{1}` are placeholders in your string, they get replaced from the other parameters to `string.Format`, in the order they are supplied.  So `{0}` would be replaced by `(i+1)` and `{1}` will be replaced by the value of `fa["id"]`

See: [String.Format Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

> Each overload of the Format method uses the composite formatting
>   feature to include zero-based indexed **placeholders**, called format
>   items, in a composite format string. At run time, each format item is
>   replaced with the string representation of the corresponding argument
>   in a parameter list. If the value of the argument is null, the format
>   item is replaced with String.Empty. For example, the following call to
>   the Format(String, Object, Object, Object) method includes a format
>   string with three format items, {0}, {1}, and {2}, and an argument
>   list with three items.

Comment: What about 0 and 1 are they index of array?

Comment: Without quotes:
    '2': '567'

Comment: 0 and 1 are indicating position in array of variables which is dynamic

Comment: @Ryba, Yes, it would be without quotes, but for explanation I left it, so it would be like `string str = "'2': '567'";`

Answer (score 2):

First, your link to the [*custom numeric format strings*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) is not related here.

[`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can be used to format a string(as the name suggests). You can use  *format items* in the string which are numbers wrapped in curly brackets. For example:

```
string text = String.Format("His name is {0}, he is {1} years old.", person.Name, person.Age);
```

will replace all occurences of `{num}` with the object with the same index as the number. Since `person.Name` is the first object after the string `{0}` will be replaced with `person.Name` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The Format function takes a string and one to many arguments, the {'number'} indicate that the string should take argument 'number' and insert it at that location.

F.i.
If i = 1 your code-snippet would add "'2':value of fa["id"]" to your strVar

(For more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "THE VARIABLE";
string.format("Here is some text {0} when I put a bracket with numbers it represents the following variables string representation", s);

//Prints: Here is some text THE VARIABLE when I put a bracket with numbers it represents the following variables string representation
```

So {0} says that replace this with the string representation of the first variable that comes after this. {1} says to take the second instead.
The alternative is to use:

```
string s = "World";
Console.PrintLine("Hello " + s + "!");
//Prints: Hello World!
```

In this small format it is readable but when you get a lot of variables it can get REALLY confusing to see what the string will become. By using the string.Format(), it will be much easier to read.

Now lets say that you have a variable that is called id and you have an array in php called fa that you want to index with id. Using the string.Format() would look like:

```
int id = 3;
Console.PrintLine(string.Format("fa[\"{0}\"]", id)); //Prints: fa["3"]
Console.PrintLine("fa[\"" + id + "\"]"); //Also prints fa["3"] but it is a lot harder to read the code.
```